# Fall planting potatoes

Tags: potatoes, fall-gardening

I am experimenting with fall planting potatoes this year. I harvested potatoes at the end of September and replanted at the same time. In the last few days some sprouts have emerged and I am wondering how these plants are likely with winter coming on.  Will they simply die back to the ground, go dormant and then re-sprout in the spring? Will this fall sprouting strategy affect the outcome of spring growth?

Comment: Maybe mulch the heck out of them.  I think I read somewhere that snow cover is helpful for some plants that can handle some cold but not too much.  Why don't you check that Swedish gardener's vlog and website?  She does a lot of winter sowing.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on if they freeze in the ground; which is a function of weather , depth , and mulch. A hard freeze will kill a potato but they might survive a light frost.

Comment: Interesting.  I've had so many volunteer potatoes come up over the years because I missed one or two during harvest that I'm not sure I understand how they could survive if this is the case.  Our frost line around here is around 40 inches - my potatoes are generally less than 12.

Comment: I may be wrong , but the U of IL said do not plant until spring . I never planted potatoes in fall.

Comment: I guess we'll find out!  Thanks for your input.  I'll try to remember to revisit this question next year with an update.